# How to get list of Azure Batch Pools and Jobs using REST API in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, rest, http-headers, azure-batch

Using REST API I want to get the list of Batch Pools and Jobs.
As per the docs:
Pool - Get | Microsoft Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/pool/get 
Job - Get | Microsoft Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/get

The API to get list of job is `GET {batchUrl}/jobs?api-version=2019-08-01.10.0` and to get pool is `GET {batchUrl}/pools?api-version=2019-08-01.10.0` 
In C# I am doing it like this:

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
using (var responseGet = client.GetAsync(api).Result) //HttpClient client
{
    if (responseGet.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        dynamic batchObjectsContent = JObject.Parse(responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
        foreach (var batchObject in batchObjectsContent.value)
        {
            batchObjects.Add(new BatchObject { Id = batchObject.id, Url = batchObject.url, CreationTime = batchObject.creationTime, StateTransitionTime = batchObject.stateTransitionTime });
        }
    }
}
```

The complete API for getting the pool is `https://mybatch.westus2.batch.azure.com/pools?api-version=2019-08-01.10.0` and api for the job is `https://mybatch.westus2.batch.azure.com/jobs?api-version=2019-08-01.10.0`.

```
Error message I am getting:
StatusCode=Unauthorized
ReasonPhrase="Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly."
error="invalid_audience", error_description="The access token has been obtained from wrong audience or resource 'https://management.azure.com/'. It should exactly match (including forward slash) with one of the allowed audiences 'https://batch.core.windows.net/'"
```

And this is how I got the access token: `authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential).Result.AccessToken;`. This works for all the APIs related to `https://management.azure.com/`.

From the errors I think there is issue with either the access token or the headers are wrong, or both. How do I correct them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Azure Batch resource endpoint to acquire a token for authenticating requests to the Batch service:

```
https://batch.core.windows.net/
```

Use the code as below:

```
private const string BatchResourceUri = "https://batch.core.windows.net/";
AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(BatchResourceUri, new ClientCredential(ClientId, ClientKey));
```

Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-aad-auth).

Comment: Can we use MSI Authentication instead of providing Client ID and Client Key?

Comment: Just in case anyone else stumbles upon this comment this was answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59212231/how-to-use-msi-authentication-instead-of-providing-client-id-and-client-key-for . You can use MSI to authenticate with Batch SDK/REST. Currently you cannot enable MSI on a Batch pool, but if you are initiating the request from a service which does support it (ie Functions) you should be able to authenticate.